# Remove near-identical rows numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[285, 849],
                [399, 715],
                [399, 716],
                [400, 715],
                [400, 716]])
```

How would I approach removing near-identical rows? I do not mind whether I end up with the row `[399, 715]`, `[399, 716]`, `[400, 715]` or `[400, 716]`. As end result I would, for instance, like to get:

```
out = remove_near_identical(arr)
print(out)

[[285 849]
 [399 715]]
```

Comment: I would use something like: import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(a[:, 0]).split(a[:, 1]). However, I would change the expression a[:, 0] so as to have each row rounded to the nearest 10 for example. I would then pick up the first element of each group.

Comment: Is there a criteria to determine near-identical?

Comment: @Divakar I suppose they can be +/- 3 apart in either column. Would probably be better if you could specify a criteria.

Comment: I'd definitely start by clearly defining your criteria. No point in doing anything until you know what you're shooting for.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, couldn't you specify that in the function itself? e.g. row distance can be at most `x`

Comment: @MennoVanDijk. Not if you want to vectorize it without numba or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes you have a 2D dataset and it retains order. Elements would be removed if they have an `average difference = ((array_1 - array_2)/#of_element) < threshold`

```py
import numpy as np


def remove_near_indentical_rows(arr, threshold):

    row, column = arr.shape
    arg = arr.argsort(axis=0)[:, 0]
    arr=arr[arg]

    arr_mask = np.zeros(row, dtype=bool)
    cur_row = arr[0]
    arr_mask[0] = True
    for i in range(1, row):
        if np.sum(np.abs(arr[i] - cur_row))/column > threshold:
            arr_mask[i] = True
            cur_row = arr[i]

    arg = arg[arr_mask]
    return arr[arg]

arr = np.array([[399, 715],
                [285, 849],
                [399, 716],
                [400, 715],
                [400, 716]])

arr = remove_near_indentical_rows(arr, 10)
print(arr)
```

Outputs

```
[[399 715]
 [285 849]]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

Well if you are not sure about the deciding the *near-identical* criteria, I think a well-known one would be based on distances among them. With that in mind some sort of distance based clustering solution could be a good fit here. So, here's one with [`sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) -

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

def cluster_based_on_distance(a, dist_thresh=10):
    kmeans= AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, distance_threshold=dist_thresh).fit(a)
    return a[np.sort(np.unique(kmeans.labels_, return_index=True)[1])]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [16]: a
Out[16]: 
array([[285, 849],
       [450, 717],
       [399, 715],
       [399, 716],
       [400, 715],
       [450, 716],
       [150, 716]])

In [17]: cluster_based_on_distance(a, dist_thresh=10)
Out[17]: 
array([[285, 849],
       [450, 717],
       [399, 715],
       [150, 716]])

In [18]: cluster_based_on_distance(a, dist_thresh=100)
Out[18]: 
array([[285, 849],
       [450, 717],
       [150, 716]])

In [19]: cluster_based_on_distance(a, dist_thresh=1000)
Out[19]: array([[285, 849]])
```

**Approach #2**

Another based on `euclidean-distance` based thresholding with `KDTree` -

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def cluster_based_on_eucl_distance(a, dist_thresh=10):
    d,idx = cKDTree(a).query(a, k=2)
    min_idx = idx.min(1)
    mask = d[:,1]>dist_thresh
    mask[min_idx[~mask]] = True
    return a[mask]
```

**Approach #3**

Another based on absolute differences between either of the columns -

```
def cluster_based_on_either_xydist(a, dist_thresh=10):
    c0 = np.abs(a[:,0,None]-a[:,0])<dist_thresh
    c1 = np.abs(a[:,1,None]-a[:,1])<dist_thresh
    c01 = c0 & c1
    return a[~np.triu(c01,1).any(0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

An method based only on distances:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

arr = np.array([[285, 849],
                [399, 715],
                [399, 716],
                [400, 715],
                [400, 716]])

# get distances between every set of points
dists = cdist(arr, arr)
dists[np.isclose(dists, 0)] = np.inf # set 0 (self) distances to be large, ie. ignore

# get indices of points less than some threshold value (too close)
i, j = np.where(dists <= 1)
# get the unique indices from either i or j
# and delete all but one of these points from the original array
np.delete(arr, np.unique(i)[1:], axis=0)
>>> array([[285, 849],
           [399, 715]])
```